Running entirely local RAG system in Colab over GDrive files?
I am trying to run an entirely local RAG using Colab on my google drive, without sending any tokens to an external language model API. I downloaded the model into a Drive folder (here just called path, but in the code it is a full filepath) and also have all the documents stored in a Chroma vector db.
When running this code,
from google.colab import drive
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline
import torch
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from llama_cpp import LlamaCpp  

drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Configuration for LlamaCpp, could experiment here? 
n_gpu_layers = 1 
n_batch = 512  

# Correct model path
llama_model_path = "path/llama-2-13b-chat.Q4_K_S.gguf.q4_0.bin"

# Initialize the LlamaCpp model
llm = LlamaCpp(
    model_path=llama_model_path,
    n_gpu_layers=n_gpu_layers,
    n_batch=n_batch,
    n_ctx=2048,
    f16_kv=True,  # MUST set to True, otherwise you will run into problem after a couple of calls
    verbose=True,
)

# Define the function to create a conversation
def create_conversation(query: str, chat_history: list) -> tuple:
    try:
        memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
            memory_key='chat_history',
            return_messages=False
        )
        qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
            llm=llm,
            retriever=retriever,  # Ensure you have the retriever properly set up
            memory=memory,
            get_chat_history=lambda h: h,
        )

        result = qa_chain({'question': query, 'chat_history': chat_history})
        chat_history.append((query, result['answer']))
        return '', chat_history

    except Exception as e:
        chat_history.append((query, str(e)))
        return '', chat_history



I get these errors:
Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name': 'path/llama-2-13b-chat.Q4_K_S.gguf.q4_0.bin'. Use repo_type argument if needed.
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
AND
OSError: Incorrect path_or_model_id: 'path/llama-2-13b-chat.Q4_K_S.gguf.q4_0.bin'. Please provide either the path to a local folder or the repo_id of a model on the Hub.
I am unsure what is wrong with the formatting, in terms of the repo_type arg.
However, I also want to make sure what I am describing is actually possible (completely local rag within GDrive). I am agnostic as to the particular language model.
I have also tried using the following code instead of the Llama model path
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    MODEL_NAME, 
    trust_remote_code=True, 
    load_in_8bit=True, 
    device_map="auto",
    repo_type = "local"
)
model = model.eval()
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

But I get the same error. If i swap the local code for downloading a model from HF, it runs as I would expect and I am able to chat with my documents.

Seems like a path issue, can you try passing the complete path?
